# Check DualPane fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

**INTRODUCTION**

From my main Activity, I call to a ListFragment. This ListFragment will open a new activity.

The difference is that if we are in singlePane mode, it will just open this, but if we are in dualPane mode, will open this ListFragment in the left side, and will let a space (empty framelayout) at the right side.

**METHOD**

To achieve this, and as I cannot start a fragment with an intent, I have created an intermediate activity to do this.

So, from my main Activity y call to this intermediate activity, and this handles to set the fragment depending if we are in singlePane or dual Pane.

This is the code:

*Start intermediate activity (MyPlacesActivity) from main Activity (GeocodingActivity):*

```
public void myPlaces () {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setClass(GeocodingActivity.this, MyPlacesActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

*Now, this is what I do on the intermediate activity to manage if the fragment must be in single or dual Pane mode:*

```
public class MyPlacesActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    boolean mDualPane;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        /*Check if we are on phone or tablet*/
        //...HOW TO DO IT!

        /*If dualPane, set the fragment in a custom layout's container*/
        if (mDualPane){
            MyPlacesListFragment listFragment = new MyPlacesListFragment();
            FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.add(R.id.list_fragment, listFragment).commit();
        }
        /*If singlePane, replace this container with the fragment*/
        else {
            MyPlacesListFragment listFragment = new MyPlacesListFragment();
            FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.add(android.R.id.content, listFragment).commit();
        }
    }
}
```

**QUESTION**

The doubt that I have is how to check if we are in phone or tablet. The MyPlacesListFragment is a ListFragment which has inflated the stock `simple_list_item_2` layout, this is way I'm trying to manage in the code above to set it in one place or another.

But as I'm still learning with this, I will accept any suggestion on modifying any code as I'm aware of that probably this isn't done in the right way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest change the way you are trying to solve the issue.

If I understood ok you could solve the problem using this approach:

Create two different xml layout, one for phones:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <fragment class="com.yourpackage.MyPlacesListFragment"
            android:id="@+id/list_fragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" 
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Save it in res/layout as main.xml f.i.

And create another for tablets, with two fragments:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment class="com.yourpackage.MyPlacesListFragment"
            android:id="@+id/list_fragment" 
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0px" 
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/right_side_framelayout" 
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0px" 
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And save it in res/layout-large with the same name as the first layout (main.xml in this case), as tablets will load the layout from this folder.

Set the main.xml as the layout for the FragmentActivty:

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

*NOTE: Up to this point you would have a differente layout for phones and tablets as you asked. If you would like to go beyond:*

You would be able to check if it´s a phone or a tablet with the following code:

```
View rightFrame = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.right_side_framelayout);
mDualPane = rightFrame != null && rightFrame .getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE;
```

And you should show the rightFrame in the same screen for tablets and in a different screen for phones when an element in the list is clicked f.i.:

```
if (mDualPane) {
  RightFragment rightFragment= (RightFragment)
  getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.right_side_framelayout);
  //replace Fragment
} else {
  Intent i = new Intent(this, RightFrameActivity.class);
  startActivity(i);
}
```

You need to have created a RightFrameFragment that will be loaded in the same screen as MyPlacesListFragments in tablets and a RightFrameActivity for phones.

(The intermediate activity it is not neccesary in my opinion as you can become your GeoCodingActivity in a FragmentActivity)

You can find more info in: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html
and its example: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Example

Hope it helps!